# How to insert an image into a BIRT report using URI properly?

Tags: tomcat, birt

I have created demo.rptdeign file using BIRT report.
I included image in rptdeign file using image URI like :-

"https://127.0.0.1/media/" + row["general_info_left_image"]

when I run report as HTML using BIRT viewer I can see images in html.
But when run report as pdf I get message "The resource of this report item is not reachable."

System Information:
Ubuntu 16.04
BIRT  4.6.0
Java Version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: Might be a permission issue. What is the image directory location. Is is writable by tomcat process/user

Comment: I have given 777 permission to image directory.

Answer (score 0):

Basically , in html format , the final report upon run , can still pull image from the mentioned URL.

However , I guess , for PDF format , a better approach is to EMBED image , so that it doesnt have to pull image file during generation .

[image]